# Include NULL row on join

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by

How can I select all rows from table_A and then join on results from other tables, but include a NULL row to show aggregate values for those other tables that don't have a table_A_id?

```
WITH RECURSIVE transactions_with_children AS (
  SELECT
    table_A_id,
    other_stuff,
    1 AS depth
  FROM transactions
  WHERE transactions.parent_transaction_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    table_A_id,
    other_stuff,
    depth + 1 AS depth
  FROM transactions children
    INNER JOIN transactions_with_children parents ON children.parent_transaction_id = parents.id
)

SELECT 
  table_A.id,
  view_B.aggregate_col1, view_B.aggregate_col2,
  view_C.aggregate_col1, view_C.aggregate_col2

FROM table_A
  -- Limit table_A to only records with data from transactions_with_children, but I also need to include
  -- a null row for all transactions_with_children that don't have a table_A_id
  INNER JOIN transactions_with_children on transactions_with_children.table_A_id = table_A.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               t.table_A_id,
               aggregate_col1, aggregate_col2
             FROM transactions_with_children t
             GROUP BY t.table_A_id
            ) view_B
    ON table_A.id = view_B.table_A_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               t.table_A_id,
               aggregate_col1, aggregate_col2
             FROM transactions_with_children t
             GROUP BY t.table_A_id
            ) view_C
    ON table_A.id = view_C.table_A_id
```

The recursive WITH tables are all scoped records from a large table. Each of the LEFT JOINs that i'm doing using this table just aggregate data from it. SUM, COUNT etc. I then join on the common table_A_id that each of the records from the WITH may or may not have.

So the problem with doing a RIGHT JOIN on transactions_with_children (I think) is that I would get tons of duplicates from transactions_with_children table. I guess I could maybe create an RIGHT JOIN sub select where I am pulling records from transactions_with_children and grouping by.

something like:

```
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT t.map_account_affiliate_id
  FROM transactions_with_children t 
  GROUP BY t.map_account_affiliate_id
) ids ON map_account_affiliates.id = ids.map_account_affiliate_id
```

I assume the join select above would include a null field if transactions_with_children.map_account_affiliate_id had any null values right?

This seems like a hacky way to do it, but i'm not all that great with SQL either.

I tried just simplifying the query for the purposes of the question, but maybe its easier to look at the original.

```
WITH RECURSIVE transactions_with_children AS (
  SELECT
    transactions.id,
    transactions.transaction_type,
    transactions.successful,
    transactions.test,
    transactions.amount_cents,
    transactions.parent_transaction_id,
    orders.map_account_affiliate_id AS map_account_affiliate_id,
    orders.t1_affiliate_tracking_id AS t1_affiliate_tracking_id,
    orders.t2_affiliate_tracking_id AS t2_affiliate_tracking_id,
    orders.id                       AS order_id,
    orders.front_end                AS front_end,
    1                               AS depth
  FROM transactions
    INNER JOIN line_items ON line_items.id = transactions.line_item_id
    INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = line_items.order_id AND orders.campaign_id IN (104)
  WHERE transactions.parent_transaction_id IS NULL
        AND transactions.successful = TRUE
        AND transactions.transaction_type IN (3, 1, 22, 5, 55, 7, 8, 22, 30, 31, 32, 33)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    children.id,
    children.transaction_type,
    children.successful,
    children.test,
    children.amount_cents,
    children.parent_transaction_id,
    orders.map_account_affiliate_id AS map_account_affiliate_id,
    orders.t1_affiliate_tracking_id AS t1_affiliate_tracking_id,
    orders.t2_affiliate_tracking_id AS t2_affiliate_tracking_id,
    orders.id                       AS order_id,
    orders.front_end                AS front_end,
    depth + 1                       AS depth
  FROM transactions children
    INNER JOIN transactions_with_children parents ON children.parent_transaction_id = parents.id
    INNER JOIN line_items ON line_items.id = children.line_item_id
    INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = line_items.order_id
  WHERE children.successful = TRUE
        AND children.transaction_type IN (3, 1, 22, 5, 55, 7, 8, 22, 30, 31, 32, 33)

)

SELECT *
FROM transactions_with_children;

SELECT
  map_account_affiliates.id                                                             AS resource_id,
  map_account_affiliates.display_name                                                   AS resource_name,
  'affiliate'                                                                           AS resource_type,
  ''                                                                                    AS parent_resource_type,
  ''                                                                                    AS parent_resource_id,
  COALESCE(sales.num_sales, 0)
                                                                                        AS num_sales,
  COALESCE(sales.num_scheduled_sales, 0)
                                                                                        AS num_scheduled_sales,
  COALESCE(sales.num_fe_sales, 0)
                                                                                        AS num_fe_sales,
  COALESCE(sales.gross_sales, 0)
                                                                                        AS total_gross_sales,
  COALESCE(sales.gross_scheduled_sales, 0)
                                                                                        AS total_gross_scheduled_sales,
  COALESCE(sales.gross_sales :: FLOAT / nullif(sales.num_fe_sales :: FLOAT, 0)
  , 0)
                                                                                        AS avg_gross_order_value,
  (
    COALESCE(sales.num_fe_sales / nullif(((SUM(sales.num_fe_sales)
    OVER ()) :: FLOAT), 0)
    , 0)
    * 100.0
  )                                                                                     AS percent_all_fe_sales,
  COALESCE((sales.gross_fe_sales :: FLOAT / nullif(sales.num_fe_sales :: FLOAT, 0)), 0) AS avg_fe_sale_amt,
  COALESCE(refunds.num_full_refunds, 0)
                                                                                        AS num_full_refunds,
  COALESCE(refunds.num_part_refunds, 0)
                                                                                        AS num_part_refunds,
  COALESCE(refunds.total_refunds, 0)
                                                                                        AS total_refunds,
  COALESCE(refunds.total_refunds :: FLOAT / nullif(sales.gross_sales, 0)
  , 0)
                                                                                        AS percent_refund_amount,
  (COALESCE(refunds.num_part_refunds, 0)
   +
   COALESCE(refunds.num_full_refunds, 0)
  ) :: FLOAT / nullif(sales.num_sales, 0) * 100.0                                       AS percent_refunds,
  COALESCE(chargebacks.num_chargebacks, 0)
                                                                                        AS num_chargebacks,
  COALESCE(chargebacks.num_chargebacks_won, 0)
                                                                                        AS num_chargebacks_won,
  COALESCE(chargebacks.total_chargebacks, 0)
                                                                                        AS total_chargebacks,
  COALESCE(chargebacks.total_chargebacks :: FLOAT / nullif(sales.gross_sales, 0)
  , 0)
  * 100.0                                                                               AS percent_chargeback_amount,
  (chargebacks.num_chargebacks) :: FLOAT / nullif(sales.num_sales, 0) * 100.0           AS percent_chargebacks,
  (
    COALESCE(sales.gross_sales, 0) -
    COALESCE(refunds.total_refunds, 0) -
    COALESCE(chargebacks.total_chargebacks, 0)
  )                                                                                     AS total_net_sales,
  (
    (
      COALESCE(sales.gross_sales, 0) -
      COALESCE(refunds.total_refunds, 0) -
      COALESCE(chargebacks.total_chargebacks, 0)
    ) / nullif(sales.num_fe_sales, 0)

  )                                                                                     AS avg_net_order_value

FROM map_account_affiliates

  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               t.map_account_affiliate_id               AS map_account_affiliate_id,
               COUNT(DISTINCT t.order_id)               AS num_sales,
               COUNT(t.id)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 22) AS num_scheduled_sales,
               SUM(t.amount_cents)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 22) AS gross_scheduled_sales,
               SUM(t.amount_cents)                      AS gross_sales,
               COUNT(DISTINCT t.order_id)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.front_end = TRUE)      AS num_fe_sales,
               SUM(t.amount_cents)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.front_end = TRUE)      AS gross_fe_sales
             FROM transactions_with_children t
             WHERE t.transaction_type IN (3, 1, 22)
             GROUP BY t.map_account_affiliate_id
            ) sales
    ON map_account_affiliates.id = sales.map_account_affiliate_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               t.map_account_affiliate_id               AS map_account_affiliate_id,
               COUNT(t.id)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 5)  AS num_full_refunds,
               COUNT(t.id)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 55) AS num_part_refunds,
               SUM(t.amount_cents)                      AS total_refunds
             FROM transactions_with_children t
             WHERE t.transaction_type IN (5, 55)
             GROUP BY t.map_account_affiliate_id
            ) refunds
    ON map_account_affiliates.id = refunds.map_account_affiliate_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               t.map_account_affiliate_id              AS map_account_affiliate_id,
               COUNT(t.id)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 7) AS num_chargebacks,
               COUNT(t.id)
                 FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 8) AS num_chargebacks_won,
               (
                 COALESCE(SUM(t.amount_cents)
                            FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 7), 0)
                 - COALESCE(SUM(t.amount_cents)
                              FILTER (WHERE t.transaction_type = 8), 0)
               )                                       AS total_chargebacks
             FROM transactions_with_children t
             WHERE t.transaction_type IN (7, 8)
             GROUP BY t.map_account_affiliate_id
            ) chargebacks
    ON map_account_affiliates.id = chargebacks.map_account_affiliate_id

WHERE map_account_affiliates.account_id = 1

      AND (num_sales > 0 OR num_fe_sales > 0 OR num_scheduled_sales > 0 OR num_full_refunds > 0
           OR num_part_refunds > 0 OR num_chargebacks > 0)

ORDER BY resource_name
```

I know this is a long messy query, but hopefully my explanation makes enough sense to get my question across.

Comment: Show us some sample data and a desired result.

Answer (score 9):

Use `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` right after your comment in the code:

> Limit table_A to only records with data from
> transactions_with_children, but I also need to include a null row for
> all transactions_with_children that don't have a table_A_id

`RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` keeps all rows from tables to the *right* of the join and adds NULL values for rows from the tables *left* of the join where none match the join condition. Your text is a bit ambiguous, you might want `LEFT JOIN` instead, which is the same with reversed sides.

[Basics in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

Comment: thanks for the response. I've posted a lot more info in hopes to better explain what i'm doing. Let me know what you think if you get a chance, and thanks again!